# How to display computer name in the output of software list code

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have created a script that pulls all of the installed software from the domain connected computers.  The problem is no matter what I do with format-table and select-object, it never seems to display the computer name, which I need to  figure out what computer has what.   The command takes an input of computers from Get-ADComputer script and runs the command for each name in the list.

I have tried properties like computername, systemname, pscomputername, and ADcomputer

```
Get-Content -Path \\server\C$\folder\Computers.txt | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*} | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate, SystemName | format-table SystemName, DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate -auto | Format-List -Property * | Out-File -FilePath \\server\C$\Folder\Computers11.txt
```

Each time it shows the computername blank

Comment: in  your `ForEach-Object` scriptblock, build a PSCustomObject that has what you want in it. that way you can skip the `Select-Object`, and the remarkably silly & destructive `Format-*` cmdlets.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for $env:computername?

$env: is essentially a drive that gives you access to all environmental variables, and computername is one that shows your current computer name.

You can list all of them with

```
Get-Item -Path Env:
```

Comment: I have tried the $env:computername and it now displays my Computername as a Header for the column and not for the rest of the list.  I'm trying to list computer names for each software that pulls up in the list.

Comment: Yes. For each software that it pulls